# Open Mac terminal in the Incognito mode?

Tags: mac, terminal, git

How do I open the Mac terminal in the Incognito mode?  Yes, I am aware about some answers like [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/625277), however, my aim is different - I do not want to use the stored passwords, etc.

I work a lot on the terminal and use Git and GitHub (one personal account and the other organizational account).  So, currently, I have to unset the details every time I want to access the other account.  Is there a way in which I could open up an in-cognito version of the terminal on Mac OS?

Comment: @dsstorefile, could you please elaborate?  I have set the global username and password in case of my git.  But these credentials are different from my organizational account's credentials.  So, I want to open incognito terminal so that the saved global credentials of my personal git won't be available in this incognito mode and I would be able to pass my new organizational credentials.